# Is it possible to create a Notification on Flutter with a countdown within the notification?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have to create a notification with the countdown and at the moment for notifications I am using this library with which I am very happy to use
flutter_local_notifications: ^ 1.2.2, but I would like to create a countdown in the notification

Comment: Do you mean a countdown for disappearance of the notification?

Comment: No, I mean a notification with the countdown inside it

Comment: Did you get it? @AlexPad?